# How to run SOAP ui tests part of maven install?

Tags: maven, testing, installation, soapui

Is there a way to run `SOAP UI tests` part of calling maven install, meaning that maven install will run those SOAP tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoapUI has a [Maven plugin](https://www.soapui.org/docs/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x/). Using the `projectFile` parameter you can point it to an existing SoapUI project. Bind its `test` goal to the `verify` phase in Maven and you should be good to go:

```xml
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>verify</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>test</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```